# How to upload photos with an article being written

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a scenario in which users write articles. When the user opens the editor it should have the facility to upload photos and include in the article. That is fine. The problem is the creation and storing of the photos. the folder of the photos for the articles is named after Id in the database so that folder is recognized for that particular article. if the user saves the article after writing and uploading photos that is fine. If the user quits and does not save the article then there remains a photo folder that is not used. So How to tackle this. if the system has to delete the folder then it is not sure whether the user has closed the brower window yet for that article or not? I am quite confused if someone has worked on similar scenario then please let me know of your precious opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could do is store the photo in `session` after uploading. Then only store it to the filesystem once the user actually `saves` the article.

Now - you have tagged both `PHP` and `ASP.Net` - so really not sure which you're using...

for this example (pseudocode) it will be in `ASP.Net`.

When the page first loads clear a session variable that will hold your image - this will ensure that it's a fresh one. so something like this - we wrap this in an `if` to make sure the page is a fresh load and not one that has posted back..

```
if (!PostBack){
    Session["usersArticleImage"] = null;

}
```

Then in your button click for your upload you can store the uploaded image into your session...

Then finally, when the user submits their article you can read the image from the session and store it to your filesystem. Once stored you can then clear the session variable again.

This idea will work regardless of your language.

If you're using a basepage of any kind (one that you inherit from for sitewide settings) then you could also put a check in there, like above, to clear the session variable for any page that "isn't" the one you have the article-editing in - that way if the user navigates away from the page after uploading, but before saving, the session will be cleared too.

Comment: Hmmm... I am using asp.net. but the user can virtually upload as much photos as he/she wants. that is too too expensive for the session.

Comment: Or just to say why not to store reference to that folder and then do the same as you suggested. but when to clear the session then and do the required stuff. if the user saves then ok, Session cleared. but if the user quits then how to find??

Comment: And actually I am already storing reference to that folder in session.

Comment: You really need to flesh out your question with as much information as possible... though yes, store references to the folders and if they haven't been committed then you can delete.